# WebRTC / Unity setup

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, webrtc, direct3d, videochat

I want to incorporate "simple" real-time video chat in my app on a Hololens. As far as read WebRTC is the way to go. So I grabbed the convenient NuGet Package of WebRTC for Windows.

`PM>Install-Package WebRTC`

I checked this two very fine examples:

http://www.cnblogs.com/Yixin-ran/p/webrtc.html

[WebRTC for UWP, new RTCPeerConnection() doesn't complete execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43331677/webrtc-for-uwp-new-rtcpeerconnection-doesnt-complete-execution/43346709?noredirect=1#comment75553022_43346709)

I learned a lot from these examples.

I also looked at the very complex chatterbox example.

My app is created in Unity. There starts my first problem. All the examples are based on WPF examples. You need the following statement.

```
 WebRTC.Initialize(this.Dispatcher);
```

This command seems to very important. But "this.Dispatcher" only exist in WPF programs. So I can't export my app as D3D program. More important.Even if I export my unity app as xaml this command only works in the Main.xaml.cs which is always overwritten by every unity export.

According to James Cadd there is a unity setup:
https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/02/22/real-time-communications-universal-windows-platform-webrtc-ortc/#PgZcxKplL46bdcST.97

Did someone have an idea how to correctly set this up in unity? Also if someone has an API link I would be grateful. I learned the syntax from those two examples so far.

Greets
Senador

Answer (score 4):

This is maybe not a good answer to your question to be posted as an answer, but I do not have enough reputation to post a comment :|

Have you seen [this answer](https://forums.hololens.com/discussion/comment/14839/#Comment_14839) in a thread regarding WebRTC use in Unity on the Hololens Developer Forum? That forum user (DanAndersen) created a set of Unity applications using WebRTC to stream video from HoloLens. I have not tested them myself yet, but hopefully they can be of interest to you.

Comment: I saw that. Thanks. :) I'm used it to set up my unity so far. But they don't describe their code. After that, I found the links up there.